# No funciona MySQLi en una web hecha con PHP desde Android

Tags: php, android, sql, mysqli, php5

Tengo un formulario en una web, y guardo sus datos en una base de datos *MySQL* usando *PHP*. Lo he estado probando con *Chrome* y *Firefox* en mi servidor local y también en un servidor externo y funciona correctamente (desde mi equipo con *Windows*).

El problema es que cuando intento hacer lo mismo desde mi teléfono móvil con *Android 8* (también con *Chrome* y *Firefox*) no se guardan los datos en la base de datos y tampoco me sale ningún mensaje de error.

¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo se soluciona?

Formulario *HTML*:

```
<form action="php/upload_img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelName"><i>Nombre</i></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Nombre" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telefonoLabel"><i>Teléfono</i></label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" max=22 required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="edadLabel"><i>Edad</i></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="edad" name="Edad" placeholder="Edad" min=18 required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fotoCaraLabel"><i>Foto1</i></label>
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="foto1"  name="Foto1" lang="es" required>
      <label class="custom-file-label" id="foto1_lab" for="customFileLang">Foto1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fotCuerpoLabel"><i>Foto2</i></label>
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="foto2" name="Foto2" lang="es" required>
      <label class="custom-file-label" id="foto2_lab"  for="customFileLang">Foto de Cuerpo entero</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Este es el código *PHP* que uso para guardar los datos:

```
function insertar_registro()
{
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $tlf = $_POST["telefono"] ;
    $edad = $_POST["Edad"];

    $tabla = "casting";
    $columns_names = "Nombre,Edad,Telefono";
    $values = "'$nombre', $edad, '$tlf'";
    $condiciones = "Nombre!='$nombre' AND Edad!=$edad AND Telefono!='$tlf'";

    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root" , "root", "myDB");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla($columns_names) 
            SELECT $values
            FROM dual
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones)";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);    

    if(!$resultado)
    {
        echo "<br>Error en la consulta:  " . $conexion->error;
        return false;
    }

    echo "El registro se ha insertado con exito";

    return true;
}
```

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Me han pedido que incluya el archivo "upload_img.php"... es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">    
    <title>Pleasure House</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>


<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function make_path()
{
    $folder = $_POST["Nombre"] . "_" . $_POST["Edad"] . "_" . $_POST["Telefono"];
    return $folder;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function subir_img($input_file_name)
{
    $folder = make_path();


    $target_dir = "/uploads/" . $folder . "/";      
    $folder_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target_dir;       


    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES[$input_file_name]["name"]);



    $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target_file;    
    $string = $file_path;
    $string = str_replace("á","a",$string);
    $string = str_replace("é","e",$string);
    $string = str_replace("í","i",$string);
    $string = str_replace("ó","o",$string);
    $string = str_replace("ú","u",$string);
    $string = str_replace("ñ","n",$string); 
    $file_path = $string;
    //echo "<br>file_path=" . $file_path;


    if(!file_exists( $folder_path ))
        mkdir($folder_path);        

    $uploadOk = true;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES[$input_file_name]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false)
        {
            ///echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            ///echo "File is not an image.";
            echo "<br>El archivo que intenta subir no es una imagen<br>";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    }


    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        ///echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        echo "<br>El archivo que intenta subir ya existe";
        $uploadOk = false;
    }




    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES[$input_file_name]["size"] > 1024*1024**5) 
    {
        echo "<br>El archivo que intenta subir es demasiado grande (5Mb max)";
        $uploadOk = false;
    }



    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg")
    {
        ///echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        echo "<br>El archivo que intenta subir tiene un formato incorrecto";
        echo "<br>Formatos permitidos (JPG, JPEG, PNG).";
        $uploadOk = false;
    }


    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == false) 
    {
        echo "<br>El archivo no ha sido subido";
    } 
    else
    {

        if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$input_file_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            echo "<br>El archivo no ha sido subido\n .";        
        }       


        ///$target_file= iconv('utf-8','windows-1256', $target_file);   
        ///echo mb_detect_encoding($target_file);


        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$input_file_name]["tmp_name"], $file_path))
        {
            ///echo "<br>El archivo ". basename( $_FILES[$input_file_name]["name"]). " ha sido subido correctamente.";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Un error ha ocurrido al subir el archivo";
            $uploadOk = false;
        }
    }
    return $uploadOk;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function insertar_registro()
{
    $nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
    $tlf = $_POST["Telefono"] ;
    $edad = $_POST["Edad"];


    $tabla = "casting";
    $columns_names = "Nombre,Edad,Telefono";
    $values = "'$nombre', $edad, '$tlf'";
    $condiciones = "Nombre!='$nombre' AND Edad!=$edad AND Telefono!='$tlf'";


    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root" , "root", "puti");


    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla($columns_names) 
            SELECT $values
            FROM dual
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones)";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);    

    if(!$resultado)
    {
        echo "<br>Error en la consulta:  " . $conexion->error;
        return false;
    }

    ///
    /*
    ?>
    <div class="txtjustyfyBlack" style="background-color:red;width:100%;margin-left:0px;text-aling:center;">
    <p style="text-aling:center;">El registro se ha insertado con exito</p>
    </div>
    <?php
    */
    echo "El registro se ha insertado con exito";


    return true;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function rmDir_rf($carpeta)
{
  foreach(glob($carpeta . "/*") as $archivos_carpeta)
  {             
    if (is_dir($archivos_carpeta))
    {
        rmDir_rf($archivos_carpeta);
    } 
    else 
    {
        unlink($archivos_carpeta);
    }
  }
  rmdir($carpeta);
 } 
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function borrar_registro_e_imagenes()
{
    $nombre = $_POST["Nombre"];
    $tlf = $_POST["Telefono"] ;
    $edad = $_POST["Edad"];

    $tabla = "casting";
    $condiciones = "Nombre='$nombre' AND Edad=$edad AND Telefono='$tlf'";

    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root" , "root", "puti");

    $sql = "DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);    

    if(!$resultado)
    {
        echo "<br>Error en la consulta:  " . $conexion->error;
        return false;
    }

    echo "<br>El registro ha sido borrado";



    $folder = make_path();
    $target_dir = "/uploads/" . $folder . "/";      
    $folder_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target_dir;
    rmDir_rf($folder_path);


    return true;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function FMain()
{

    if(!insertar_registro())
        return;

    if(subir_img("foto1") && subir_img("foto2"))
    {
        echo "<br>Muchas gracias por enviarnos tu solicitud.";
        echo "<br>Nos pondremos en contacto contigo si eres seleccionada para ocupar las plazas libres.";

        ?>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div class="boton txt_center">
                <a style="color:black" href="../index.html">Volver a la página principal</a>
            </div>
        <?php       
    }
    else
    {
        borrar_registro_e_imagenes();
        ?>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div class="boton txt_center">
                <a  style="color:black" href="../casting.html">Intentarlo otra vez</a>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FMain();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aparentemente tu codigo es correcto,aunque la funcion `insertar_registro` no deberia imprimir mensajes (eso deberia hacerlo la funcion que le llama).. podrias poner el codigo del archivo upload_img.php?

Comment: voy a ver si lo encuentro... hace 4 meses que hice esta pregunta :-) ... pero creo que aún tengo el código por algún lugar

Comment: perdona, he visto la pregunta hoy pero no me he fijado que era "editada"... Si ya lo tienes resuelto entonces no te lies :)

Comment: No, no estaba resuelta... de hecho aún me preocupa este asunto porque ahora ando metido en una cosa parecida y me conviene que funcione en telefonos moviles. (El archivo que me pedias lo encontré y lo acabo de poner ahí arriba).

Comment: has probado cambiadno `<button type="submit">` a `<input type="submit">`

Comment: No lo recuerdo... pero lo probaré... te contaré que tal me fue en cuanto lo haga. Gracias por la idea!!

Comment: Probé lo del submit pero no funcionó... lo raro es que ahora tampoco funciona desde el Pc y hace 4 meses si lo hacia... No se que habrán hecho los de hosting... voy a tener que mirarlo con calma en cuanto tenga tiempo... gracias por la ayuda!!